# Scala: Two underscores followed by colon parsed as one token

Tags: scala, playframework

I was playing around with Play's JSON library recently, and noticed that this doesn't compile:

```
val steps = Seq("a", "b", "c")
steps.foldLeft(__)((a, x) => a \ x)
```

After a little tinkering and browsing the source, I found the correct expression:

```
steps.foldLeft(JsPath())((a, x) => a \ x)
```

or even:

```
steps.foldLeft(__())((a, x) => a \ x)
```

...although the second one is looking pretty obfuscated.

Later on I found a more efficient and concise expression:

```
JsPath(steps.toList map KeyPathNode)
```

But I kept on returning to the original expression and playing around with it.  I found that this works:

```
steps.foldLeft(JsPath: JsPath)((a, x) => a \ x)
```

Somehow, this doesn't:

```
steps.foldLeft(__: JsPath)((a, x) => a \ x)
```

I get `error: not found: value __`.  However, this works:

```
steps.foldLeft((__): JsPath)((a, x) => a \ x)
```

This works too:

```
steps.foldLeft({__}: JsPath)((a, x) => a \ x)
```

Also this:

```
steps.foldLeft(__.asInstanceOf[JsPath])((a, x) => a \ x)
```

Why is it that the expression with `__: JsPath` fails?

...Aaaaaand just before I was about to submit this question I found another working expression:

```
steps.foldLeft(__ : JsPath)((a, x) => a \ x)
```

It seems the parser is interpreting `__:` as one token.  But why would it do that?  I thought underscore is just another valid identifier character.  Is there some special-case parsing rule that's responsible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore is special in identifiers precisely because it can be followed by operator characters, including `:`: e.g. `foo_+` is an identifier, where `foo+` is two tokens: `foo` `+`.

> [First, an identifier can start with a letter which can be followed by an arbitrary sequence of letters and digits. **This may be followed by underscore `_` characters and another string composed of either letters and digits or of operator characters.**](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers)

Note that `_` and `$` are considered uppercase letters for the purpose of the first sentence here. So `__:` is a legal identifier, but `_:` is not.

Comment: Not allowed to upvote in comment, but clickable quote is very handy. Just to add info: underscore is lower case for pattern varid: `42 match { case __: => __: }`. Now we need a use case. I once tried extended underscore for aligning case arrows, but now maybe I'll try `42 match { case __========> => () }`

Comment: That's curious. I asked about this at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/sh20Vr2BK9Y.